# How to get different size icons on desktop and in folder window (16.10)?

Tags: nautilus, icons, zooming

After an upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 I have found that changing the size of the icons in a folder window changes the size of the icons on the desktop.  This is a new behaviour AFAIK.  Is there a setting to decouple the two size settings?